# How can I add an index to a LINQ query when there is a grouping?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ statement that works

```
     var separator = new[] { " ||| " };
        var objectives = data.Select(s => s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .GroupBy(strings => strings[0])
            .Select(grouping => new Objective
            {
                Text = grouping.Key,
                ObjectiveDetails = grouping.Select(s => new ObjectiveDetail { 
                    Text = s[1]
                }).ToList()
            })
            .ToArray();
        return objectives;
    }
```

What I would like to do is to populate a field called Number inside the Objective 
object and a field called Number inside the ObjectiveDetail object. I want the 
number to start at one and be incremented so each new Objective and ObjectiveDetail
inside gets a new number assigned to it. I tried to do the following:

```
     var separator = new[] { " ||| " };
        var objectives = data.Select(s => s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .GroupBy(strings => strings[0])
            .Select(grouping, index => new Objective
            {
                Number = grouping.Index,
                Text = grouping.Key,
                ObjectiveDetails = grouping.Select(s, index => new ObjectiveDetail { 
                    Number = index,
                    Text = s[1]
                }).ToList()
            })
            .ToArray();
        return objectives;
    }
```

This gives me an error on the .Select(grouping, line saying "The name grouping does not exist". Can someone help tell me how I can fix this and add an index to the GroupBy ?

Comment: It looks like that your `Objective` has only one `ObjectiveDetails`? Because I can see one `Objective` is corresponding to the `s[0]` while the `ObjectiveDetails` is corresponding to `s[1]`, so the `Number` for `ObjectiveDetail` doesn't make much sense (it's always `1`), it makes sense only when an `ObjectiveDetails` has many/some `ObjectiveDetail`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just got the syntax wrong for a lambda with two parameters: `.Select((groupings, index) => expression)`